# Saber quando clico numa div o valor na tabela PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte problema. Quero obter quando clico numa div, um valor de um array. Ou seja faço uma consulta a minha tabela, a obter o valor. O problema é que tenho sempre o primeiro valor.
Aqui esta a função que faz a consulta

```
function select($dir, $base, $i){                       
    //for($y=$arraylenght; $y>0; $y--){ 
    $array_resultados = array(); //array    

    $arraylenght =15;
    for($y=1; $y<=$arraylenght; $y++){ 
        $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);                    
        $requete    =   "SELECT id, title, start, end, description, jour, mois, annee, date 
            FROM \"event\" 
            WHERE jour=\"$i\"
            AND id=$y";

        $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);     
        $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();
        array_push($array_resultados, $affiche); //insert in array

    }

    return $array_resultados;
}
```

E a div

```
if($day==$i)
{   
    $array_resultados = array(); //array    

    //function pour montrer les evenements dans le array        
    $array_resultados=select($dir, $base, $i);

    $titles = ""; //variable inicialize
    foreach($array_resultados as $key =>$value){
        $titles .= "<div class=dois onclick='popup(\"_popup_cal.php?jour=$i&moisEcris=$months[$moisaff]&annee=$year&mois=$month&txttitle=$txttitle&txtstart=$txtstart&txtend=$txtend&txtdescription=$txtdescription&maj=$maj&clean=1&teste=$txttitle\",400,300)';>
                                ".$value['title'].
                                "</div>"; //save in variable value  
    }
}
```

O problema é que tenho sempre a mesma div a ser gerada. Nao consigo distinguir na qual clico.

Comment: você quer mostrar o valor correspondente a uma `<div>` que está armazenado numa base de dados quando é dado um clique na mesma?

Comment: Certo, o problema é que é feita uma div sempre que adiciono um evento na base de dados. Eu pretendo saber quando clico na div, enviar para outra pagina algo para saber para depois alterar esse so registo, e não so o primeiro. que é o q m esta a acontecer.

Comment: faça um `var_dump($array_resultados)` para ver o que está a ser trazido da base de dados

Comment: sim dentro do array tenho os dados.

Comment: `$value['title']` está sempre a imprimir o mesmo valor?

Comment: Não,imprime os valores bem que esta na base de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Por que não experimenta usar javascript/jquery e $.ajax para fazer a requisição ? Segue um exemplo básico.

js

```
$('#div-alvo').on('click' , function(){
    $.ajax({
            url : <caminho do arquivo.php> ,
            dataType : 'json' ,
            data : <variavel que deseja enviar> ,
            success : function(){} ,//caso tenha sucesso, executa as linhas abaixo
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            //Caso tenha erro, mostre no console o erro
               console.log(errorThrown);    
            }
});
```